# Unable to load new kernel version in RedHat 7.3

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have RedHat Enterprise Linux Server 7, with kernel: 3.10.0-514  and I downloaded the linux kernel version 4.12.10 and I compile it and configure it without having any error here are the commands I executed:

```
make mrproper
make dep
make clean
make  bzImage 
make modules
make modules_install
```

the execution was done without errors.
then I copied the file `System.map` to `/boot folder`, executing:

```
cp System.map /boot/System.map-4.12.10
```

and then

```
cp arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage /boot/bzImage-4.12.10
```

But when I retstart the OS, I do not have the option to load the new kernel.

Any help please ?

Comment: grub also has to be configured

Comment: Did you update your boot loader with the new image? Also, you will have to generate a new initramfs, if you are using one.

Comment: No I did not how can I do this  ?

Comment: Recreating the `initramfs` might be important as well before reconfiguring `grub`.. `mkinitrd /boot/initramfs-<kernel-version>.img <kernel-version>`, where <kernel-version> is the folder from `/lib/modules`.

Comment: @Thomas done with success, now what shoul I do to reconfigure the grub ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `initramfs` first :

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k <kernel name>
```

For **Rhel** :

```
dracut -f -v /boot/<kernel name>
```

And then update your `grub` :

```
sudo update-grub
```

For **Rhel**:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg ##For BIOS based machines.
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg #For UEFI based machines.
```

Comment: these commands do not work in redhat

Comment: @rainman Updated answer for Rhel.